# Поиск максимально возможной суммы элементов двухмерного массива

Tags: php, массивы, алгоритм

Имеется массив целых положительных чисел размерами n на m. Можно брать только один элемент из каждой строки и столбца. Необходимо найти максимально возможную сумму элементов и отобразить их.

образец массива:

```
350 250 250 100 100 100 100 100 42  21  42  84  0   0   0
250 250 250 100 100 100 100 100 0   0   0   0   63  0   0
350 250 250 100 100 100 100 100 0   21  42  84  21  15  15
150 190 250 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
350 250 250 100 100 0   100 100 42  42  42  63  63  15  15
300 250 250 100 100 100 100 100 21  21  0   63  84  0   0
250 250 190 100 100 100 100 100 0   21  21  0   0   0   0
300 220 250 0   0   0   100 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
350 250 250 0   0   0   100 0   21  0   0   21  21  0   15
```

максимальный размер n - 25, m - 35

язык желательно php, но подойдет и псевдокод

Comment: И в чём проблема? поиск в ширину, например, подойдёт.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Задача сводится к задаче о назначениях и решается [Венгерским алгоритмом](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC)**

Дополним матрицу до квадратной 10-ю строками нулей. Это не изменит значение максимальной суммы. Затем решаем задачу о назначениях для квадратной матрицы ([Венгерский алгоритм](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC)).

Comment: ссылки на описание алгоритмов и т.п. это скорее комментарий чем ответ.

Comment: @teran А каким может быть ответ на такой вопрос, если есть известный алгоритм? Детально расписать алгоритм и привести полную реализацию?

Comment: @MBo  а почему бы и нет? SO позиционируется как база знаний,а не база ссылок на википедию и гугл. Конечно, мб полный код писать уж слишком, но хотя бы вкратце изложить алгоритм и т.п. По факту ведь тут действительно только ссылка на сторонний источник, как по мне, на качественный ответ это не тянет.